# Which one is better, pointer to other class or inherit from that class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pointers

I want to know which is better way for this problem:

A teacher can teach more than one subject or can take more than on lab or may be both in a institute. `Lab`,`Subject`,`Teacher` also have some other variables. I did not write them all here. 
New `lab,subject and teacher` can be added individually. When a teacher is added I only input all variables of `Teacher class` and `labCode` and `subCode`. There are some Labs and Subjects which are predefined and others which are added later. I can view record of a teacher which shows his Lab and Subject details also if available.

My concepts in c++ are not too strong and I don't know which one is better for this. Should I give a pointer in Teacher class to Lab and Subject class or should I inherent them, or is there any better way to do this.

```
class Lab{
    char labCode[20];
    char labName[40];
        int labYear;
    //here default constructor 
};
class Subject{

    char subCode[20];
    char subName[20];
        int subYear;
    //here default constructor 
};
//-------------------------------------
class Teacher{
    char facName[30];
    int teacherSubCount;
        int teacherLabCount;
    Subject *subject;
        Lab *lab;
    //here default constructor 

};
//------------or should i do like this--------------
class Teacher:public Lab,public Subject{
   char teacherName[30];
    int teacherSubCount;
        int teacherLabCount; 
   //here default constructor 

};
```

If you can suggest any tutorials so I can learn the power of a pointer as my book states "pointers are very  powerful c++", but they only give some simple examples :)

Comment: Logically, Teacher should know about Lab and Subject, but he can't be derived from Lab or Subject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Favor 'object composition' over 'class inheritance'." - [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

More specific to your classes, though, first ask yourself... "Is a Teacher a type of Lab or a type of Subject?"  Clearly, the answer is "no."

In an inheritance model, the child class should itself be an instance of the parent class.  Considering the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), that child object should be treatable as that parent object.  So if there's code that's looking for a `Subject` you would be able to pass it a `Teacher`.  Intuitively, that doesn't make much sense and is not an accurate representation of the real-world domain entities being modeled.

In this case you definitely want object composition instead of class inheritance.  The `Teacher` *has a* `Lab` and *has a* `Subject`, not *is a* `Lab` or *is a* `Subject`.  Indeed, if the `Teacher` can *have* multiple `Lab`s or `Subject`s then the composition would simply change from a single instance class member to an array or list of some kind.  Whereas the inheritance approach would break entirely in that case.

When modeling objects that represent real-world concepts like this, consider intuition of those real world concepts foremost and the technical shortcuts to implementation secondary.  If it doesn't make sense in terms of what's being modeled, then it won't make sense in the code either.

Comment: ok i understand what should i use and where but another question come in mind is that lets a teacher teach more than one subjects than how i point all the subjects and what should i if he assigned one more subject. i know how to work with fixed length objects but when length is varied i really not understand what to do..

Comment: and any book which strong my concept of pointer with objects in c++ . i know what is object, class,inheritance ..etc terms but how to extend my knowledge to use them properly.

Comment: @NatwarSingh: If a `Teacher` can have (or in some way be associated with) more than one `Subject` then I imagine the class member would be an array of `Subject`s.  I don't know the specifics for C++, but in C# I would use an `IEnumerable<Subject>` or an `IList<Subject>` to represent a list of `Subject`s.

Comment: @NatwarSingh: If you're using basic pointers, a `Subject*` can point a single `Subject`, or it can point to the first `Subject` in an array of `Subjects`. You would just need some member indicating how many you are using. Myself, though, I'd just use a `std::vector<Subject>` for this: a vector can hold 0, 1, or many objects of the templated type.

Answer (score 3):

Think about whether the 'is-a' (for inheritence) and 'has-a' (for aggregation) relationships make sense in your proposed solution

A `Teacher` is neither a `Lab` nor a `Subject` - I think you should go with the aggregation solution.

However, what you really need to get completely sorted before you get started on the code is your data model. You need to identify the relationships and multiplicity (i.e. one-to-one, one-to-many etc.) between the objects.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance implies a "is-a" relationship, while a pointer implies a "has-a" relationship.

Is a teacher a lab? Is a teacher a subject? No, it has a subject and it has a lab, so it's a "has-a" relationship. So you should use pointers, in this case.

Why inheritance wouldn't work would become apparent when you would try to change the lab of a teacher. You can easily change the object a pointer is pointing to, but replacing all the data of the base class is a lot more cumbersome.

To give an example where you would use inheritance, EnglishTeacher could inherit Teacher, because it is also a teacher, but with additional abilities.

Comment: I'm not sure that even "has-a" corresponds.  There's a relationship, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the common sense approach:

Inheritance expresses an `is-a` relationship. A teacher is obviously
neither a `Subject` or a `Lab` and this would be a serious eye-brow
raiser. So I'd say aggregation (a `has-a` or `has-many`) is the way to
go.

You will also need to decide if you are using value semantics
or reference semantics. That means will equality be actual equality of
objects in your program or will equality be computable through certain
parts of your object.

If you use reference semantics you will need to make sure you are
using smart-pointers or some other form of memory managment, otherwise
things get ugly really quickly.

Comment: Since more than one teacher can teach a given subject, you can't very well use value semantics.  And teachers don't own the subjects in any way; there's nothing here to recommend using any type of smart pointer I know of.

Comment: @JamesKanze How does many teachers for one subject matter if equality is value equality? For the smart pointer: Why wouldn't a `shared_ptr/weak_ptr` work here?

Comment: If `Subject` has value semantics, then there's no problem (and no need for pointers).  In an OO design, it's likely not to be the case.  And `shared_ptr` certainly wouldn't work; whether a specific `Subject` exists is independent of whether any teachers are teaching it or not.  (Also, anytime you need to use `weak_ptr`, you might as well forgo the smart pointers completely, because the analysis as to which pointers have to be weak is more complex than manual memory management.)

Answer (score 1):

When you *inherit* a class, as in your last example, think of it as *extending* that class' existing, defined behavior. In that vein, then, ask yourself the question: Does a "teacher" enhance the capabilities of a "lab"? To me, the answer is clear - they don't - they're entirely different objects, so inheritance isn't the ideal way to model these elements in your problem domain. A teacher *has* a class, a class *has* a subject, and so on - hence, aggregation seems to be a better path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You will understand the concept, if you look at this example:

```
void doExperimentsIn( Lab &room ){...}
```

If you derive `Teacher` from `Lab`, you will be able to do experiments inside a `Teacher`, too. (Which is silly.)